# Separation of variables - limits of integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sampling, monte-carlo

In [this book](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/people/cmbishop/prml-book/), section 11.1.1 on sampling methods (rejection sampling) we generate $z$ from a uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$ and then transform $z$ using a function $f$ so that $$y=f(z).$$

The distribution of $y$ is then: $$p(y) = p(z) \, \bigg\lvert\frac{dz}{dy}\bigg\rvert \tag{1}$$

and in this case $p(z) = 1$. It is then stated that by integrating equation $(1)$ we obtain:

$$ z = h(y) \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{y}p(\hat{y}) \, d\hat{y} \tag{2}$$

which is the indefinite integral of $p(y)$ and thus $y=h^{-1}(z)$.

My question is simply how the limits in $(2)$ integral come about (and surely they must have been applied to both sides)?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: It's probably worth pointing out that $h$ is now the CDF of $p(y)$.

Comment: It's given by the support of $y$, which is assumed to be $\mathbb{R}$. Assuming that $h$ is bijective, the two cumulative distributions $\int_0^{z} p(\hat{z}) d\hat{z}=\int_0^{h(y)}d\hat{z}= h(y)-0=\int_{-\infty}^\hat{y}p(\hat{y})d\hat{y}$ have to match.

Comment: I'm still a little unclear, could you elaborate further please?

Comment: For a start, why did you choose to integrate $p(\hat{z})$ between $0$ and $z$?

Comment: $z$ is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. Then, the cumulative distribution function is given by $\int_{-\infty}^z p(\hat{z})d\hat{z}=\int_{0}^z d\hat{z}$, because $p(\hat{z})$ is zero for $\hat{z}<0$ and $1$ for $0 \le \hat{z}\le 1$. Finaly, you simply substitute $z=h(y)$. The last step only works, because $h(y)$ is bijective.

Comment: Also note, there's a typo in my first comment. The last part of the equation should be $\int_{-\infty}^y p(\hat{y}) d\hat{y}$ as your equation above.

Comment: The underlying basic idea: If $\hat{z} = h(\hat{y})$ is a strictly increasing function of $\hat{y}$ (as assumed by the book) the probability of observing $\hat{y}  < y$ is the same as  $\hat{z}  < h(y)$ and $\int_{-\infty}^z p(\hat{z})d\hat{z}=\int_{-\infty}^y p(\hat{y})d\hat{y}$. For the stated uniform distribution of $\hat{z}$ it follows that $h(y)$ is the cdf of $y$.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - though I don't have the reputation to vote.

Comment: You are welcome.